# my msys2 home has moved from a linux like one to a windows like one. How to restore it?

Tags: setup, msys

I have installed [MSYS2](http://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/wiki/MSYS2%20installation/). First, I had my HOME in `/home/Laurent`, `/` being `c:/msys64` in Windows. Then I made different thinks, install [Mingw](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/), [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html), and especially [msysgit](http://msysgit.github.io/), which has its own MSYS setup. Then when I run a MSYS2 shell, my HOME is now the Windows one: `c:/Users/Laurent`. Probably I did some weird things.

In `/etc/profile`, I can read:

```
  # Here is how HOME is set, in order of priority, when starting from Windows
  #  1) From existing HOME in the Windows environment, translated to a Posix path
  #  2) from /etc/passwd, if there is an entry with a non empty directory field
  #  3) from HOMEDRIVE/HOMEPATH
  #  4) / (root)
```

So it seems that my MSYS2 has "switched" to the default HOME (1). Here is `/etc/passwd` concerning my account:

```
Laurent:unused:1001:513:U-Win7\Laurent,S-1-5-21-1379731639-3004223336-974672684-1001:/home/Laurent:/bin/bash
```

Shall I replace it with:

```
Laurent:unused:1001:513:S-1-5-21-1379731639-3004223336-974672684-1001:/home/Laurent:/bin/bash
```

to restore my initial setup ? I am not sure of the syntax of this line which is not familiar to what I know from standard Linux distributions, and I would not like to mess my setup and possibly loose my shell history.

Comment: I tried my own suggestion after doing a backup, it does not work.

Comment: I have discovered that the Windows environment variable HOME is used by `/etc/profile`. So I have modified it to `c:/msys64/home/Laurent` and it works. Surprisingly, `pwd` returns `/usr/home/Laurent` instead of `/home/Laurent` I expected. /usr exists in the shell, but is not in *Windows Explorer*. Besides, `/` and `/usr` are identical like if `/usr` was a soft link to `/` - touching a file is repercuted in the other and in c:\msys64\.

Comment: The msysgit home was not affected. Its /etc/profile does not manage HOME the same way. I think it works because it has not permissions on the MSYS2 tree, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the Windows environment variable HOME solves the problem.

Under Windows 7, go to START Button / Computer / Context menu -> Properties / Advanced system parameters / Advanced system parameters tab / Environment variables, then select HOME and *Modify*.

Warning: my translation in english may not be the exact one you may have on your system.